# Update/Edit using Modal form in laravel with Script

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I need help to fix my script it can not update the data but it can show , how can i fix that? am i missing a route or something? 
 This is My Modal Form

```
<form action="/device" method="POST" id="editForm">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      {{ method_field('PUT') }}

       <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
       <label>Serial Number</label>
         <input type="text" name="Serial_No" id="Serial_No" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Serial number">
       </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Data</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default float-right">Cancel</button>
       <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default float-middle">Clear</button>
    </form>
```

This is my script

```
//Start Edit Record
        table.on('click', '.edit', function () {

        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        if ($($tr).hasClass('child')) {
          $tr = $tr.prev('.parent');
        }

        var data = table.row($tr).data();
        console.log(data);

        $('#Serial_No').val(data[1]);

        $('#editForm').attr('action', ''+data[0]);
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
        });
        //End Edit Record
```

Comment: your question is quite vague. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You don't submit the form, you only set the action to some value.Do you want do show a modal or to submit the form?

Comment: with that code and script it can show but you can't edit and submit to make updates

Comment: @djunehor am trying to update data via a modal form but it can only show the data and when you try to make a change it can't update

Comment: Perhaps you need to provide more code. `table.on('click', '.edit', function () {`. There's no element with classname edit in the html you provided

Your jquery code seem to be trying to make the modal popup. And you're dynamically changing the URL the form is supposed to submit to

Comment: can you help me out on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
$('#editForm').attr('action', '{{ URL::to('/device',$deviccs->id) }}'+data[0]);
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
        });
```